# Windows 365 Enterprise Setup

Tags: entra-id, azure-networking, microsoft-365

I'm going to sign up for Windows 365 and have a few questions that will help me with my decisions.

Currently, we do have an Azure Subscription but do not have a VNET. We also use Azure Active Directory and do NOT have any on-prem network or domain controllers. So, we're 100% cloud based.

With that said, do I need Windows AD to use Windows 365? I'm just watching some of the videos and they kind of go real fast in that section but I do get the feeling that we may need Windows AD. Is that true? Or is that a requirement for the Enterprise version?

Creating a VNET is not a problem but I'm particularly concerned about needing a Windows AD because if I'm not mistaken, we'd have to spin up at least one VM for that and set it up as a domain controller. I guess we'd then have to worry about doing some type directory syncing between Windows AD and AAD. I really would like to avoid all of this.

I'd appreciate some pointers on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this article. It seems like the Enterprise version does have additional requirements and if one needs to be up and running quickly, the Business version is the right choice.

https://www.itpro.co.uk/operating-systems/microsoft-windows/360457/how-to-get-started-windows-365